# How to find the previous element of the specified element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find the previous `img` element present before the specified element. But when I run my code it returns `undefined`.

My code is:

```
 $(document).on('keypress','#sendComment', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13){
        var itemId=$('#findbefore').prev('.SharedImage');//
        console.log(itemId);
        var dataid=itemId.data('id');
        var dataalid=itemId.data('alid');
        var datashareid=itemId.data('shareid');
        var alt=itemId.attr('alt');
        alert(dataid +' '+dataalid+' '+datashareid+' '+alt);
    }
});
```

This was printing `Object[]` in console and `undefined undefined undefined undefined` in alert.

And my divs are :

```
 <div id="S04" class="snew" style="display: block;">
 <div class="author-image"></div>
 <span>ajay shared the image xyz</span>
 <div class="s-content">
 <div class="s-message"></div>
 <div class="shpicture">
 <img class="SharedImage" width="100%" height="100%" data-shareid="1" data-alid="1" data-id="1" alt="xyz" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,">
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="SPcommentbox" id="findbefore">
 <div class="comment">
 <div class="commenter-image"></div>
 <div class="addcomment">
 <input id="sendComment" class="commentbox" type="text" placeholder="Write a comment...">
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

I need to find the attribute values of `img`. When user press enter button.

**Note : I'm adding these divs with jQuery**

Please anyone help me to solve this ... Thanks...

Comment: The answer will be very specific to exactly the HTML structure you've presented, which is quite complicated. It's also very unclear from your question exactly what your starting point is. Is it that you want to find the "previous" `.SharedImage` starting from `#findbefore`?

Comment: @Forty-Two: It's there, it's a `div` with the class `SPcommentbox`.

Comment: Just saw it and deleted my comment.  Thanks!

Comment: @Forty-Two you can see the id in this div `<div class="SPcommentbox" id="findbefore">`

Comment: @T.J. Crowder yes I need to find the first `.SharedImage` starting from `#findbefore`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.prev()` will only match the *immediately* preceding element, and if you've supplied a selector, only if it matches that selector.

Given the existing HTML snippet you need:

```
$('#findbefore').prev().find('.SharedImage');
```

However I'm concerned about whether there might be multiple such elements on the page?  You may get a fuller answer if you supply more HTML.

For example, you *might* be better off with:

```
$(this).closest('.SPcommentbox').prev().find('.SharedImage');
```

Alternatively, if there's guaranteed only one `.sharedImage` on the page, then you should give it an ID instead of a class, and access it directly:

```
$('#SharedImage')
```

Comment: Yes I have more `.SharedImage`. the code is same as above it repeats from #S04,S05,... to all below codes.. `id="findbefore"` and `id="sendComment" ` will added and removed by jquery when user enters and exits from the `div`.

Comment: @JamesRobinson IDs are not supposed to be transient like that - it means you have to use event delegation to catch events on them (as you are, but it's inefficient).  How are you catching the user "entering" the div?  With `mouseenter`?  What if the user can't use a mouse?

Comment: Given code in your answer also producing the same result. My problem remains same

Comment: I had a lower case 's' in 'sharedImage' - try it now.

Comment: Ohhhh! Thanks I didn't observed that, I just copied... Now it working... Thank you very much..